# Sort the data using pandas - sort on first column conditional on values in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I tried to get the below input data with `awk, sort, sed`. I am feeling it might be too complicated to handle them using those unix utilities. Proabably `pandas` might be good.

**These are the conditions for sorting the data.**

- first sort the column #1 in increasing order.
- now, within each column #1 group the data based on same keys in column #3 (sort order not important).
- Now, sort the column #2 based only on the very smallest value for each group in col#3.

  **For eg:**

  - for group-4 (in col#3) the smallest value in col2 is 15882592 which is << group-5 (in col#3) smallest value 15883889; So group-4 should be on top of group-5.
  - Similarly, for group-5 (in col3) smallest value is in col2 15883889 <<  group-1 (in col3) smallest value 15885010; So group-5 should be on top of group-1.

So, finally I have to group col#1 first and then column#2 conditional (grouped) on col#3.

**Input Data:**

```
2   15881989    6
2   15882091    6
2   15882148    6
2   15882328    6
2   15882364    6
2   15882451    8
2   15882454    8
2   15882493    8
2   15882592    4
2   15882601    4
2   15882607    4
2   15883765    4
2   15883782    4
2   15883783    4
2   15883785    4
2   15883861    4
2   15883862    4
2   15883889    5
2   15883894    5
2   15883904    5
2   15884457    5
2   15884525    5
2   15884546    4
2   15884550    4
2   15884582    4
2   15884613    4
2   15884649    4
2   15884742    4
2   15884965    4
2   15885010    1
2   15885024    1
2   15885061    4
2   15896126    4
3   15896174    4
3   15896152    4
3   15896128    3
3   15896224    3
3   15896258    3
3   15896406    3
```

**Expected output:**

```
2   15881989    6
2   15882091    6
2   15882148    6
2   15882328    6
2   15882364    6
2   15882451    8
2   15882454    8
2   15882493    8
2   15882592    4
2   15882601    4
2   15882607    4
2   15883765    4
2   15883782    4
2   15883783    4
2   15883785    4
2   15883861    4
2   15883862    4
2   15884546    4
2   15884550    4
2   15884582    4
2   15884613    4
2   15884649    4
2   15884742    4
2   15884965    4
2   15885061    4
2   15896126    4
2   15896128    4
2   15896152    4
2   15883889    5
2   15883894    5
2   15883904    5
2   15884457    5
2   15884525    5
2   15885010    1
2   15885024    1
3   15896128    3
3   15896224    3
3   15896258    3
3   15896406    3
3   15896152    4
3   15896174    4
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `transform` `min` as new key

```
df.assign(New=df.groupby(['col1','col3']).col2.transform('min')).sort_values(['col1','New'])
```

Comment: for some reason it doesn't seem to be working; even for the given input data.

Comment: Also, I would like update on this answer; since this is shortest way to get this accomplished.

Comment: Just to add to the comment. It works when I do `new_df = df.assign(New=df.groupby(['col1','col3']).transform('min')).sort_values(['col1','New'])` with an extra `New` column, which I can delete. Also, I don't see `col2` indicated at all, which becomes a problem if I multiple columns but I want `min value` only from `col2`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
import pandas as pd

# assume df.columns = ['1', '2', '3']

# calculate order
d = {x: df[df['1'] == x].groupby(['3'], as_index=False)['2'].min()\
        .sort_values('2')['3'].tolist() for x in set(df['1'])}

# enumerate order and store in dictionary
d = {k: {w: i for i, w in enumerate(v)} for k, v in d.items()}

# apply order by '3' in new column
df['order'] = df.apply(lambda row: d.get(row['1']).get(row['3']), axis=1)

# sort by each column
df = df.sort_values(['1', 'order', '2']).drop('order', 1)

#     1         2  3
# 0   2  15881989  6
# 1   2  15882091  6
# 2   2  15882148  6
# 3   2  15882328  6
# 4   2  15882364  6
# 5   2  15882451  8
# 6   2  15882454  8
# 7   2  15882493  8
# 8   2  15882592  4
# 9   2  15882601  4
# 10  2  15882607  4
# 11  2  15883765  4
# 12  2  15883782  4
# 13  2  15883783  4
# 14  2  15883785  4
# 15  2  15883861  4
# 16  2  15883862  4
# 22  2  15884546  4
# 23  2  15884550  4
# 24  2  15884582  4
# 25  2  15884613  4
# 26  2  15884649  4
# 27  2  15884742  4
# 28  2  15884965  4
# 31  2  15885061  4
# 32  2  15896126  4
# 17  2  15883889  5
# 18  2  15883894  5
# 19  2  15883904  5
# 20  2  15884457  5
# 21  2  15884525  5
# 29  2  15885010  1
# 30  2  15885024  1
# 35  3  15896128  3
# 36  3  15896224  3
# 37  3  15896258  3
# 38  3  15896406  3
# 34  3  15896152  4
# 33  3  15896174  4
```